# Use relative path in BrowserWindow.loadURL

Tags: electron

My dir structure is this:

```
./
--/main
----index.js
--/app
----index.html
```

From `./main/index.js` I am trying to launch `./app/index.html` like this:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width:500, height:500, backgroundColor:'#CCC' });
    mainWindow.loadURL('../app/index.html');
```

However it is not working. May you please show me how to do this with relative path?

Answer (score 2):

you should use `__dirname`

so your code should look like:

```js
app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width:500, height:500, backgroundColor:'#CCC' });
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../app/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
});
```